# How to analyse huge output from Reduce systematically?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, output

I have a constrained optimization problem, looking for Nash equilibria. I use the KKT conditions programmed using Reduce to solve it. For the general case I get a very large output, with more than 100 different solutions(and this is  just trying with a very simple setting). This is an example of one solution:

```
w[1] > 0 && Inequality[0.5, Less, a, Less, 1.] && 
Inequality[0, Less, b[1], LessEqual, (1. - 2.*a + a^2)/a^2] && 
Inequality[0, Less, b[2], Less, 1.] && 
Inequality[(-1.*a*b[1]*w[1])/(-1. + a), LessEqual, w[2], LessEqual, 
(w[1] - 1.*a*w[1])/(a*b[2])] && x == 0 && y == 0 && 
λ[1, 1] == (-1.*a*b[1]*w[1] + w[2] - 1.*a*w[2])/(w[1]*w[2]) && 
λ[1, 2] == 0 && λ[2, 1] == 
(w[1] - 1.*a*w[1] - 1.*a*b[2]*w[2])/(w[1]*w[2]) && 
λ[2, 2] == 0
```

The main problem is that the different solutions are not even consistent in terms of ordering of variables. For example I would think that it is a good idea to look at it in a table where columns contain expressions for the individual variables and parameters, and rows represent solutions.

Is there a way to force `Reduce` or apply some transformation to it's output which would enable us to see better what is going on within so many solutions? It doesn't have to be just reordering of variables, other ideas on how to understand the solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say that such systems should be solved numerically instead...

Comment: I was hoping to understand a bit more generally the whole solution set instead of just getting a set of points. For concrete parameters it also gives unique solutions so it's not an issue to use it in that sense

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: @m_goldberg it feels quite general to me, can I do something particular to make it of more use according to you? Interpreting big outputs from `Reduce` doesn't seem to be uncommon...

Comment: If your question is to be taken as general and the your code is only an meant as example — that is, if you are asking for a general treatise on extracting info from `Reduce` — then it is too broad.

Comment: Please include in the question the Mathematica code that produced the solution given in the question.